# Rendering issue /Found cyclical <include> chain in one layout of project - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, rendering, layout-xml

I am working in Android Studio. It is android version 2.3.2, 7.0 (nougat) and API 25. For my layout/XML file I am getting Rendering Problem and also Found cyclical  chain: activity_maps includes activity_maps.

I have looked at other StackOverflow posts and changed the API to a lower version, changed the style.xml file by adding "Base." to get     .

This problem is still re-occuring, and I don't know what else to do. All of my other layouts/XML design works except this one. This uses maps to get the direction between two points. Below is the XML file:

```
 <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="edu.usf.cse.labrador.familycare.MapsActivity"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etOrigin"
    android:hint="Enter your address" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Find path"
        android:id="@+id/btnFindPath" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_distance"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0 km"
        android:id="@+id/tvDistance" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_clock"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0 min"
        android:id="@+id/tvDuration" />
</RelativeLayout>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/activity_maps" />
```

[What i see for this layout.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3QwU.png)

In the design option I don't see anything. The layout is blank.

Please let me know if you have any advice on how to resolve this issue.

Thank you! Really appreciate it.

Comment: I suspect you fixed it already and also suspect you just missed the closing LinearLayout tag, but just for completeness, did you forget to put in the closing LinearLayout tag?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be it but you are missing the closing Linear Layout.

I put it in and it comes up on my screen.

```
</LinearLayout >
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove/change the following in your fragment tag:

```
 tools:layout="@layout/activity_maps"
```

if cant display a layout of itself